# How to create dynamic attribute in rails for Active Record update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have some variables that I get from the `Get/Post` requests =>

`params[:status], params[:value] #:value has the value of the :status`

and I would love to use the `update` method of the active record to update the record (validation needs to be run). How can I then create a dynamic query like

```
@user.update(status: value)
```

I have tried this.

```
attribute = { params[:status] => params[:value] }
user.update(attribute)
```

but this does not call any validation. Validation is IMPORTANT for me here.

Answer (score 2):

Update will call validation, but you need to change how you're building the attribute, as `params[:status]:` is not a valid construct.  Use....

```
attribute = { params[:status] => params[:value] }
```

Comment: sorry that was just a typ in the question. its weird, now i can see that it does not pass the validation. the same code basicly. maybe i was using a wrong value before

Comment: Possibly, but in any case glad your problem is sorted!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `send` method to call a method (attribute) dynamically on your object

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Object.html#method-i-send

```
status = params[:status]
user.send("#{status}=", params[:value])
user.save
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of doing this

```
attribute = { status: value }
user.update(attribute) // this should run validation for sure.

user.assign_attributes(attribute)
user.save(validate: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If more than one **field** and **value** separate with a comma

`attributes = {"firstname"=>"John", "surname"=>"Stack"}`

In your case

`attributes = {params[:status] => params[:value], params[:name] => params[:value]}`

Or convert to string if need be

`attributes = {params[:status].to_s => params[:value].to_s, params[:status].to_s => params[:value].to_s} //default is string`